# automating matlab code but functions are not found despite being on my Matlab path

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I am having a problem with Matlab.

I have a c# wrapper that creates an instance of Matlab and changes the directory to where I have various functions located. I then call the required Matlab function.

The problem occurs when that function makes a call to another function that is not in the same directory but is on my Matlab path. Matlab says it can't find the function. Just to make the situation more confusing some functions that are in a different directory do work.

In my Matlab I have a startup.m file that loads all my required paths. Is this executed when making an instance of Matlab via C#?

If I run the code manually from Matlab the code works perfectly.

```
 MLApp.MLApp _matlab;


  try
        {
            // create matlab instance
            _matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

            // change to the directory where the function is located            
            _matlab.Execute(@"cd G:\MyPath\production\SomeFolder\");

            // define the output
            object result = null;

            // call the matlab function upload_data            
            _matlab.Feval("someFunctionName", 0, out result, "parameter");

            // quit matlab
            _matlab.Quit();

            // display result
            object[] res = result as object[];
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _matlab.Quit();
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: Just a guess. Are you sure that you call just public functions, and not private ones?

Comment: all the functions are public. I believe I have found the problem. I don't believe when creating an instance of matlab the path is loaded apart from the default paths

Comment: You may have to put ' ' around the path. `_matlab.Execute(@"cd 'G:\MyPath\production\SomeFolder'");`

Comment: The `startup.m` file that MATLAB loads is the one in the current directory. It won’t look for it on the path (as far as I know). Thus, you should put that `startup.m` file in the directory that is current when you execute the `matlab` command (or create the MATLAB instance in your C# code). Simply change directory before doing that.